# Fix the search results on top of a container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen that looks like this:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <FavoritePointInput
              textChangeHandler={textChangeHandler}
            />
          </View>
          <LocationsFound
            addressesFound={locations.favAddressesFoundList}
          />
          {/* <View style={styles.fixed}> */}
          <View style={styles.fieldDescription}>
            <Text>Set Location's Name:</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <Item style={styles.searchField}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Library"
                onChangeText={(text) => setLocationName(text)}
                style={styles.searchText}
              />
            </Item>
          </View>
        
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button style={styles.button}>
              <Text>Save Location</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      {/* </View> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Its Stlyes are as like this:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  topContainer: {
    height: moderateScale(750),
  },
  topTextContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: moderateScale(15),
    height: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(30),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(30),
  },
  topMiddleContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  topMiddleText: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 40,
  },
  searchFieldContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(120),
  },
  button: {
    width: moderateScale(120),
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  searchField: {
    width: moderateScale(300, 0.3),
    height: verticalScale(40),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(3),
    borderRadius: verticalScale(10),
  },
  fieldDescription: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  fixed: {
    position: 'absolute',
  }
});
```

When I write something in the first input field, I get search results through the `LocationsFound` component. That disturbs the whole style and pushes the second input field downwards. I want it to simply overlap and come on top of the second field until one of them is selected. Is that possible?

[image]

[image]

Edit:
[image]

Comment: @matvs Your response has nothing to do with react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, it looks like `<LocationsFound>` is your dropdown. You need to style this component and provide an absolute position to it to remove it from the normal positioning flow of the UI. Note, you position absolute works relative to its nearest positioned ancestor, therefore you will also need to relatively position its parent.

In your markup.

```
<LocationsFound
  styles={styles.dropdown}
  addressesFound={locations.favAddressesFoundList}
/>
```

And in your styles

```
searchFieldContainer {
  position: relative,
  // other attributes
}

dropdown {
  position: absolute,
  // adjust top and left according to your situation e.g. 10px
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes my the Locations Found hide behind the second input field. I added a picture in the qs

Comment: @Jnl Try to add a `zIndex` to your dropDown selector.

Comment: Add a z-index to your styles and set it to a positive value as pointed by @monkey-0001